# Create a list from a list using a statement that call the second element of each index

Tags: python, list, sorting, if-statement

This is my initial list:

```
    >>> List1 = (List.most_common())
    >>> print (List1)
    >>> [('d', 17), ('a', 17), ('c', 17), ('q', 6), ('w', 4), ('s', 3), ('i', 2), ('p', 2), ('f', 2), ('h', 2), ('n', 2), ('g', 2), ('j', 2), ('u', 1), ('b', 1)]
```

Generated from a text, it is the number of times each letter appears in the text.

```
    >>> HighestFactor = List1[0][1]
```

HighestFactor = 17 is what i get, as the highest number that letter(s) appears is always gonna be on that position

What I need to do is get the one that appears most, on this case, ( "D", "A" and "C" ) if there are more then 1 with the same number of appearance sort them alphabetically, if not just print the letter.
I first though on creating a list that only have the ones equals to the HighestFactor, so i could sort alphabetically that list and get what i need

```
    >>> Last_list = for (x,y) in List1
                     if y = HighestFactor:
```

This was the closest i could get from the solution, i think, but it didn't worked.

Think on it as :

('d', 17) = (x,y)

('a', 17) = (x,y)

('c', 17) = (x,y)

and the

17 = y = HighestFactor

Do a list with only the elements that have their y = HighestFactor.

Result should be :

```
    >>> print Last_list
    >>> [('d', 17), ('a', 17), ('c', 17)]
```

Comment: As a matter of style, you should not capitalize variable names in Python. Also don't use `list` (or `List`) as a variable name, as it's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: You could use `filter(lambda x: x[1] == max(List1, key=lambda x: x[1])[1], List1)`, whether or not that's readable.

Comment: Wait, your question says you want them sorted alphabetically, but your sample output is ordered (d, a, c) rather than (a, c, d). Is that just an oversight?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I need to order them alphabetically if theres more then 1 with the same number of appearance on the list, so it should be the last step

Comment: @MarkReed Yes Mark, i had to rename my variables to put on the github because i'm Brazilian and they were on Portuguese, then i used the first thing that came up to my mind hahaha my mistake, i knew about now using names that are commands, but not about the capitalize, thank u for the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
max_val = max(x, key= lambda y : y[1])[1]
max_lst = filter(lambda y: y[1] == max_val, x)
sorted_lst = sorted(max_lst, key = lambda z : z[0])
```

The first line selects the maximum value from the list, the second line creates a list that is comprised only of values equal to the maximum, and the third line sorts the result alphabetically.

Comment: Where x is my list ?
Where on this  `max_val = max(x, key= lambda y : y[1])[1] ` u take the values from the maximum ? what do i should change if i wanted the third value or even the first value ? From all of the solutions thats my doubt, i don't know on the codes they gave me where the "magic" happens, where on their codes they change the index, or put y and not x and then the second value is what they get, and not the first or anyother

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the data is not sorted,

```
data = [('d', 17), ('a', 17), ('c', 17), ('q', 6), ('w', 4), ('s', 3), ('i', 2), ('p', 2), ('f', 2), ('h', 2), ('n', 2), ('g', 2), ('j', 2), ('u', 1), ('b', 1)]

max_count = max(data, key=lambda datum: datum[1])[1]
tops = sorted(alphabet for alphabet, count in data if count == max_count)
```

Since you want the output to be sorted ...

Comment: I see it, but can u explain how it works ? like, what i don't know is how to filter the second element from each element on the list, where does this code 
`max_freq = max(data, key=lambda datum: datum[1])[1]`
filters the y knowing that ( d, 17 ) = (x,y) ?

Comment: `max` will find maximum element based on the key -- the second element of each tuple in the data `[1]`. It returns `('d', 17)`. Since we want 17, we get that by `[1]` at the end. Now, you go through the list, and check alphabets you want to retrieve if its count matches to the highest one. Built-in functions (max, sorted), unpacking, generator, and anonymous functions are all important in writing not only concise but also easily readable code.

Comment: Thanks u very much =)
One last question
`phabet for alphabet, count in`
Knowing  that( x, y ) here is where u are saying that **x = alphabet** and **y = count** , right ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's break this down a bit.

It looks like you're starting with a `Counter` instance, judging from the `most_common()` call. That's a good start. `most_common` is sorted by counter value, which is what you want.

To take only the elements of `most_common()` that share the highest value, I'd use `itertools.takewhile()`:

```
highest_count_iter = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x[1] == counter.most_common(1)[1], counter.most_common())
```

Or, if you prefer to break that down a bit too:

```
elements = counter.most_common()
highest_count = elements[0][1]
highest_count_iter = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x[1] == highest_count, elements)
```

That will give you an iterator that yields only the pairs that share the highest value.

You can then sort this without bothering with a sort key, because Python tuples are sorted element-wise and you know the elements all share the same count for their second value:

```
print sorted(highest_count_iter)
```

Comment: thanks for not using a N**2 algorithm like most of the other answers ;P +1

Comment: I think they're all still n log n (for at least one sort), just making extra passes to take the max and/or filter. Not that it's the biggest concern if this sticks to counting, say, letters in the latin alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

Given you can get the`HighestFactor` you'd want to use a list comprehension:

```
final = [x for x in List1 if x[1] == HighestFactor]
```

A faster way that uses the python functional builtins might be:

```
final = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == HighestFactor, List1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import takewhile
LastLettersList = zip(*takewhile(lambda x:x[-1] == HighestFactor,List1))[0]
```

maybe?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
>>> a = [('d', 17), ('a', 17), ('c', 17), ('q', 6), ('w', 4), ('s', 3), ('i', 2), ('p', 2), ('f', 2), ('h', 2), ('n', 2), ('g', 2), ('j', 2), ('u', 1), ('b', 1)]
>>> mx = max(map(lambda x: x[1], a))
>>> sorted(filter(lambda x: x[1] == mx, a), key=lambda x: x[0])
[('a', 17), ('c', 17), ('d', 17)]
```